# Spring GraphQL authentication error handling

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-graphql

I am using [Spring GraphQL](https://spring.io/projects/spring-graphql) and [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) in my project. I am authenticating users with JWTs so I have a security filter to check the validity of the token. When the token is invalid, an exception is thrown.
I am trying to return the message of the exception as a valid graphQL response but all I get is this:

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "message": "Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read",
    "stack": "TypeError: Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read\n    at http://localhost:8080/graphiql?path=/graphql:78:33"
  }
}
```

The error I am getting in the console is this:

```bash
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The input is not a valid base 64 encoded string.
```

So, I want that in the "errors" "message".

This is the Security configuration:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;
    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService, JwtFilter jwtFilter) {
        this.appUserDetailsService = appUserDetailsService;
        this.jwtFilter = jwtFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/graphiql").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and this is the jwtFilter:

```java
@Log4j2
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    private final AppUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public JwtFilter(JwtUtil jwtUtil, AppUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @NotNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @NotNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        try {
            if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwt = header.substring(7);
                username = jwtUtil.getUsername(jwt);
            }

            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authenticationToken.setDetails(
                            new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how could I achieve that?

Thanks!